# catch error message and create Journal entry

Tags: linux, bash, syslog

The following code I put on top of many scripts I am using...

```
#!/bin/bash

# redirect all error messages to the protocol,
# then print the same message to stdout
exec 1> >(logger -i -s -t $0 -p 4) 2>&1
```

This line of code will make protocol entries of errors occurred while running my scripts.
But this code doesn't work like I want when communicate via `stdin` and `stdout`. I want to log error messages only.

And to be honest, I don't know how I managed to get this line of coding to work.

Nonetheless, I am searching for a code to replace this combination of `exec` and `logger` <s>with a `function` put in `trap "createErrorMessage" ERR`.</s> But I don't know how to catch/receive error messages this way.

My goal is to create protocol entries of all error messages only.

To be clear, I don't want to use `$?` after every piece of code and I don't want to catch every piece of code with `Variable=$()`.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `systemd`? It's not referenced in the question at all. It's also not clear what's meant by "protocol entries of error messages".

Answer (score 1):

While `logger` sends output to `syslog`, `systemd-cat` performs the same kind of function for `systemd`.   See for example:

```
echo "hello" | systemd-cat
journalctl | tail -10
```

If you are running your scripts as systemd service units, then there's no need to use `systemd-cat`: By default `systemd` will send STDOUT and STDERR of services it controls the journal.

See `man systemd-cat` for more about that tool.

Comment: Sorry, my post was missleading, so I updated it. yeah, I know `systemd-cat`. It works similar to `logger` with few less functions. I dont use my scripts as a service, so I am bound to tools like `systemd-cat & logger`, but I want to create entries of error messagesa only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do not understand what do you want, but let say have this script `mytest.sh`:

```
date > jj
cat jj - jjj    # jj + stdin + (nonexistenxt) jjj #e.g. error too
mkdir jj        #error
```

so, when you will use this as script with redirections,

```
echo "Hello world" | bash mytest.sh > output
```

you will get:

1.) in the file `output`

```
Thu Apr  6 21:21:13 CEST 2017
Hello world
```

and on the screen - the errors

```
cat: jjj: No such file or directory
mkdir: jj: File exists
```

Now, change the above script too

```
((

date > jj
cat jj - jjj    # jj + stdin + (nonexistext jjj)
mkdir jj    #error

) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee >(logger -i -t $0 -p 4)) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

Note, the removed the `-s` from the logger args.

Now when you will use it again

```
echo "Hello world" | bash mytest.sh > output
```

- in the output will be the `stdout` as you expected
- the stderr will do to screen (and you can redirect it again)
- and the logger will log all errors.

As you sure know, it works

- swaps the stdout and stderr
- pipes the stdout (now the stderr) to the logger process
- swaps the stdout/stderr back

It probably could be simpler, because the logger by using the `-s` could duplicate the messages into the stderr itself, but this works universally. Unfortunately, it is inefficient thus using 2 more forks. note the `((`.

Using the:

```
somefunc() { some actions...; }
trap 'somefunc' ERR
```

will not help you as you expecting. Doing some fancy redirections in the `somefunc` is too late, because the `somefunc` triggered **after** the error happens, e.g. the error-message is already printed to `stderr`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the clamps `((` ? Maybe using `exec`again with your code ?

Comment: @suleiman not really, because the 1st subshell has the swapped and the second swaps back. You need the middle because of the `tee`. But maybe someone will bring some better solution.. :)